# Webhook Streaming Connector for Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

As per the **Apache Flink** documentation, It has [Predefined Data Sources](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/datastream_api.html#data-sources).
It also mentions there are some other [connectors](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/#bundled-connectors) eg.RabitMq Connector etc.
I am wondering if there is any similar project available to use **Webhook** as Data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no webhook data source for Flink, but there is a socket connector.

There has been some preliminary discussion about adding something like a webhook ingress for Flink's [Stateful Functions](https://flink.apache.org/stateful-functions.html), where such a data source is a more natural fit.